# Событие по клику esc срабатывает только на второй раз js

Tags: javascript, escape

Есть функция, которая меняет стиль кнопки при открытии/закрытии fullscreen видео на сайте. При закрытии видео с помощью кнопки Esc класс не меняется (а должен). Но если нажать на Esc повторно, событие отрабатывает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка, почему событие по нажатию кнопки Esc срабатывает только на второй раз?

```js
const openFullscreen = () => {
  if (document.fullscreenElement === null) {
    videoWrap.requestFullscreen();
    videoFullscreenButton.classList.add("active")
  } else {
    document.exitFullscreen();
    videoFullscreenButton.classList.remove("active")
  }
}

videoFullscreenButton.addEventListener('click', openFullscreen);
document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  if (e.key === "Escape" && videoFullscreenButton.classList.contains("active")) {
    videoFullscreenButton.classList.remove("active");
  }
});
```

Демо (в разделе Video): https://rolling-scopes-school.github.io/murimolda-JSFEPRESCHOOL/portfolio/

Comment: Потому что событие вешается при клике.

Answer (score 1):

Разобралась, переделала функцию

```
    const openFullscreen = () => {
        if (document.fullscreenElement === null) {
            videoWrap.requestFullscreen();
        } else {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        }
    }

    videoFullscreenButton.addEventListener('click', openFullscreen);

    document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", () => {
        videoFullscreenButton.classList.toggle("active");
    });
```